# WCF authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

if i am using HttpClientCredentialType.Basic as ClientCredentialType and i only need wcf authentication for security should i worry about certificates and https?

Comment: This question also matters on hosting, if the services are all inside the same firewall and aren't accessible external you don't **need** SSL. But I would never create a web service that doesn't use SSL.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't use transport security then the basic authentication can be sniffed.
So, it depends on how secure you need your app to be.

Comment: Agreed; Transport-with-client-credential would be preferred

Answer (score 2):

HttpClientCredentialType.Basic means you send your user name and password virtually in plain text. You must never use it without transport level security if it is production code.